# Infinite dimension of a polynomial ring as a vector space

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, vector-spaces

In my algebraic geometry book, they claim that the polynomial ring $k[x_1,...,x_n]$, as a vector space, has infinite dimension. I am trying to show this, but I have no idea of where to start. Any suggestions?

Comment: $1, x , x^2 , \dots , x^n , \dots$ are all linearly independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vector space has base like $x_1^{m_1}\cdots x_n^{m_n}$ where $m_i\in \Bbb{N}$. Clearly there is no limit for such bases. So it has infinite dimension.

Comment: Although this is going in the right direction, it could use some better redaction.

Comment: Even the subspace $k[x_1]$ has infinite dimension since $1,x_1^1,x_1^2,\ldots$ is linearly independent.

Comment: For $n>0$  and real polynomial $p(x)$ with $\deg (p)<n$ ,the equation $x^n-p(x)=0$ has only finitely many solutions.So the function $x^n$ is linearly independent of $x^0,...,x^{n-1}.$